# ArgumentCountError caused by wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php

Tags: custom-post-types

when we give $depth in argument of nav_menu_css_class it gives me argument error. Here is my code:

```
  add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class' , 'eodwp_menu_item_class',10 ,3 );
  function eodwp_menu_item_class( $classes, $item, $args, $depth) {  
    print_r($depth);
     if ($depth == 0) {
      $classes= array('dropdown');
      print_r($classes);
  }
  else {
      $classes= array('dropdown-item');
  }
  return $classes;
  }
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function eodwp_menu_item_class(), 3 passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\akeo_template\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php
>   on line 289 and exactly 4 expected in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\akeo_template\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Akeo-Tech\functions.php:27
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\akeo_template\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(289):
>   eodwp_menu_item_class(Array, Object(WP_Post), Object(stdClass)) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\akeo_template\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(206):
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\akeo_template\wordpress\wp-includes\class-walker-nav-menu.php(153):
>   apply_filters('nav_menu_css_cl...', Array, Object(WP_Post),
>   Object(stdClass), 0) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\akeo_template\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-walker.php(144):
>   Walker_Nav_Menu->start_el('', Object(WP_Post), 0, Object(stdClass)) #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\akeo_template\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-walker.php(244):
>   Walker->display_element(Object(WP_Post), Array, 0, 0, Array, '') #5
>   C:\x in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\akeo_template\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Akeo-Tech\functions.php
>   on line 27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number in the last argument to `add_filter()` needs to match the number of arguments accepted by the callback function. Your function now accepts 4 arguments:

```
function eodwp_menu_item_class( $classes, $item, $args, $depth) {
```

So that last number needs to be `4`:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'eodwp_menu_item_class', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Perfect, learned something new. Now I know that the last param represents the number of args